# determines the largest and smallest just with if code

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that determines the smallest and largest number among the 5 numbers received from the user, but I have only managed to determine the smallest and I feel it is also wrong and I can only determine with the if command...Thank you for helping me friends

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a, b, c, d, e;

    cout << "Enter 5 integers in a b c d e\t:\t";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    if (a < b && c && d && e)
        cout << "smallest number is a";

    if (b < a && c && d && e)
        cout << "smallest number is b";

    if (c < b && a && d && e)
        cout << "smallest number is c";

    if (d < b && c && a && e)
        cout << "smallest number is d";

    if (e < b && c && d && a)
        cout << "smallest number is e";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put them all in an array, sort the array, print the first or last element of the array depending on if you want largest or smallest. Maybe its not the best solution, but its much better than writing an if block for every permutation of checking that a single variable is larger than the rest. Look up those topics, make an attempt with them, and edit your question with that attempt. Right now, your question lacks focus.

Comment: `if(a<b&&c&&d&&e)` does NOT check if `a` is less than all of `b, c, d, e`. Instead, what this does is it first checks if `a < b` is true, then checks if `c` is true, then checks if `d` is true, then checks if `e` is true (an int is considered "true" if it's not equal to 0). This means that even if `a` is not the smallest number in the input, as long as b, c, d, and e are all not equal to 0, you'll still output that the smallest number is a. To fix this, use `if(a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e)` for your first condition and similarly for the other ones.

Comment: Or briefly, `if(a<b && c && d && e)` is equivalent to `if( (a<b) && (c) && (d) && (e) )`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you still need to specify what you are testing to be the smaller number in your if statement like so

```
if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
{
  cout << "The smallest number is " + a;
}
```

and then to find the largest you can do it the same way but of course using a > b && a > c

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I modify a optimized code which has more effectiveness on time complexity.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter 5 integers in a b c d e\t:\t";
    int total = 5;
    int max, min, a;
    cin >> a;
    max = min = a;
    while (total-- >= 2) {
        cin >> a;

        if (a > max) {
            max = a;
        }
        if (a < min) {
            min = a;
        }
    }

    cout << "smallest number is " << min << endl;
    cout << "biggest number is " << max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```